# Mysql nested case with DAYOFWEEK

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get this nested case working and need some help as it is showing syntax error. The part where I am having trouble is the count case as afterhour. What I am trying to get is if status = 'ended' and if booking.date = 'Saturday' or 'sunday' count++.

pseudo-code:

```
if(booking.status == 'ended'){
   if(booking.date == 'saturday' or booking.date == 'sunday'){
        count++;
   }
}
```

Mysql query

```
SELECT
    staff.StaffID,
    staff.First_name,
    staff.Last_name,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN booking.Status = 'ended' THEN booking.duration ELSE 0
    END
) AS duration,
COUNT(
    CASE 
    WHEN(booking.Status = 'ended') 
    THEN 
        CASE 
        WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(booking.Booking_date) = '1' OR DAYOFWEEK(booking.Booking_date) = '7')
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
) AS afterhour,
COALESCE(
    SUM(booking.Status = 'cancelled'),
    0
) AS
STATUS
FROM
    staff
LEFT JOIN booking ON staff.StaffID = booking.convenerID
GROUP BY
    staff.StaffID
```

Comment: The syntax error is that you have two started nested CASE statements in afterhour, but only one of them has an END. If you need help with the logic of the query itself, you should probably add some sample data and a desired result since it's a bit of a guessing game otherwise.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for noting it, I think that was the issue. Thank you.